# How to rename Task groups in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-task-groups

Is there any easiest way to rename a `taskgruop` in `Azure DevOps`?
To rename a `taskgroup` in `Azure DevOps`, I have to follow below steps,

```
 1. Export the task group
 2. Update the exported JSON with new taskgroup name
 3. Import the exported JSON
```

Comment: That's right, and you can refer here to know more detailed information about task group https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops#manage-task-groups. Since your question has been fixed, you can mark your answer and it wil help other users with the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can easily edit taskgroup name by clicking on taskgroup and changing the value in 
"Properties->Name"

[image]